# How to get all records using algolia REST api

Tags: angular, algolia

I am trying to retrieve all records from **algolia** using get method with angular.

I am using browse but still unable to getting 1000 records.

**Here is the REST api url trying to hit:**
this.http.get(`https://${appId}-dsn.algolia.net/1/indexes/${index}/browse?x-algolia-application-id=${appId}&x-algolia-api-key=${apiKey}&${param}`)

Could you help me anyone?

Answer (score 0):

When you say

> I am trying to retrieve all records from algolia using get method with angular

do you mean that you are you using the [Angular InstantSearch](https://www.algolia.com/doc/guides/building-search-ui/what-is-instantsearch/angular/) UI library? If so, should have the Algolia [Javascript API client](https://www.algolia.com/doc/api-client/getting-started/install/javascript/) installed too as a peer dependency. Depending on the context of your use case, you might consider using the JS client's [browseAll](https://www.algolia.com/doc/api-reference/api-methods/browse/?language=javascript) method to export all records from your index.

There are handy examples [in the docs here](https://www.algolia.com/doc/api-reference/api-methods/browse/?language=javascript#examples).

If you're looking to build a user-facing search experience, I'd recommend simply using the `search` method and paginating results most of the time.

If you're just looking for a fast way to export the contents of your index, you might try using the [Algolia CLI](https://github.com/algolia/algolia-cli) tool, installed with npm: `npm i -g @algolia/cli`.

With the CLI, you could export all your records with a single command like `$ algolia export -a yourAppId -k yourApiKey -n yourIndexName -o ~/Desktop/example_folder/`